# How can I find documentation for android:listSeparatorTextViewStyle?

Tags: android, xml, android-studio, styles

Given the following line of xml

```
style="?android:listSeparatorTextViewStyle"
```

Where can I find online documentation for the style? So far, I have used F1 in Android Studio to bring up documentation within Android Studio. This states:

```
?android:attr/listSeparatorTextViewStyle => @style/Widget.Material.Light.TextView.ListSeparator
```

I then go to https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/refs/heads/master/core/res/res/values/styles.xml

I then search for "Widget.Material.Light.TextView.ListSeparator" with no results. Any help on this would be appreciated.

Comment: Requests for documentaiton are off topic here.  But ignoring that-  what type of documentation are you looking for?  Its a style, used as a list separator between textviews.  How it looks will vary depending on device.  There's really not much to document.

Comment: Okay, thanks for letting me know. I'm looking for a general approach, to be able to find out how each style is defined (e.g. which attributes it defines), so that I can decide which ones to use in my own programs.

Comment: Just reading http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic, bullet points three and four read: software tools commonly used by programmers; and is
a practical, answerable problem that is unique to software development. Is my question not covered by this description? I'd be happy not to ask questions here of this nature again if this is the general consensus.

Comment: It's question vs asking for documentation. If you asked "what does this style do? "It may not be a great question but is on topic. Asking for documentation our tutorials is off.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this link on android developer forum : [Dev link](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.attr.html#listSeparatorTextViewStyle)

Let me try it and hope that helps:
Method 1: Once you have declared your style for the view, and trying to add a component, like textview, imageview, button etc and declaring the attributes then, if you click "Command + Space" is shows the available attributes.

Method 2: Manual
If you are trying manually, then as you know what theme you are using, try to find the particular component's name find all attributes/properties available for it as showing in pic.[image]

Comment: Thanks sumandas. I'd already found that and it doesn't tell me which attributes the style defines. I'm looking for a resource that would help me learn what each does.

Comment: Little confused, isn't this the link of all attributes available?

Comment: Apologies. Okay, here's what I'm getting at. A text book I'm using states: "A style is an XML resource that contains attributes that describe how a widget should look and behave." Is the line style="?android:listSeparatorTextViewStyle" making reference to a particular style? If so, what particular attribute(s) does it use to describe a widget? And what general approach can I use to find out the answer to this last question for any chosen style?

Comment: @mlm Updated the answer, hope this throws a little more light.

Comment: Thank you for your detailed post. Using your Method 2, when I search for "Theme.Material" on the page https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/refs/heads/master/core/res/res/values/themes.xml I don't get any search results. Am I looking on the wrong page?

Comment: I see now that I should have been looking at https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/master/core/res/res/values/styles_material.xml. Many thanks!